# In Bash, how do I stream the end of a pipeline into a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I know that any variable set at the end of a pipeline is lost (excluding with the shell option in Bash 4 - unfortunately this needs to be a portable solution).  However, I am sure there must be a way with file descriptors or something to stream the output of the end of a pipeline into a variable, even if via some convoluted route! :)

Ideally I want a command/function that takes one argument, the name of a variable that will eventually result in containing the output of the rest of the pipeline.

I have got a function that will find its next free file descriptor in a portable fashion:

```
getFd ()
{
    # we'll start with 3 since 0..2 are mapped to standard in, out, and error respectively
    local myFD='3'
    # we'll get the upperbound from bash's ulimit
    local FD_MAX=$( ulimit -n )
    local FD_LOC
    if [ -e /proc/$$/fd ]
    then
        FD_LOC="/proc/$$/fd"
    elif [ -e /dev/fd ]
    then
        FD_LOC="/dev/fd"
    else
        return 1
    fi
    while [ -e "${FD_LOC}/${myFD}" ] && [ "${myFD}" -le "${FD_MAX}" ]
    do
        ((++myFD))
    done
    eval FD="${myFD}"
}
```

I am thinking I might need to do something like previously creating a pool of open file descriptors that can be pulled in via some alias jiggery pokey or something, but am hoping that I am missing some much simpler way as am sure there must be a better way.

I was also thinking that if I added `printf %s "${myFD}"` at the end I could do something like `alias '{FD}'="$( getFd )"` to implement the Bash 4 feature of automatically finding the next available file descriptor for use in the form of `{FD} <filename` note: the need to have a space, but if this can be made to work it would be great to bring this feature to bash 3.0 for example.  Also, would probably have to use `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

P.S.  I am trying to avoid having to force the `MyCommand MyVariable < <( command1 | command2 ; ) ;` type syntax and and am striving if it is possible to end with the: `$ command1 | command2 | MyCommand MyVariable ;` type of use.

Comment: You appear to be trying to do something that is too complicated for a shell script. Consider writing a Perl or Python script instead.

Comment: Your question sounds really interesting, however it is not easy to understand. Here are some questions your readers might ask themselves: Why are those variables lost? What shell option are you talking about? What end of a pipeline - I thought they had two? Why don't they just use command substitution? What problem can be solved by this or is it just syntactic sugar?

Comment: How does that function work? The `$$` in `FD_LOC` isn't expanded anywhere that I can see. Also why `eval` on that last line?

Comment: I assume you want something more than having the function write contents to a pre-arranged (or passed via number) fd that you then read from on the next line? How "tricky" do you want to get with the required running environment for this? I don't think you can get the command itself to do this so you'll need *something* in the environment to do the variable setting somewhere.

Comment: Hey, the $$ is a standard "special" bash variable, (Bourne as well I believe) that gives you the PID for the shell you are in at the time of evaluation.  This ties in with those that use the `/proc` filesystem to determine the next available fd as the structure is `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` where `<pid>` is the pid of the shell and <fd> is the file descriptor files that reside there.  This is kinda syntactic sugar, although I am using it to build a much more friendly and sensible way of intreating with the shell through some well needed language extensions. :)

Comment: My point wasn't that I didn't understand `$$`. It was that you use it in single quotes (so it doesn't expand) and then use the variable that contains `$$` later (where it doesn't expand) so you get a literal `$$` in the expansion when you use it in the `[ -e` test.

Comment: Ha ha, you are entirely correct, apologies for the confusion, I copied an earlier version of my function to here by mistake.  I will update it now so that the $$ is surrounded with double quotes! :-)

Comment: Also, I don't want anything more complicated than to read from a pre-arranged file descriptor to a variable, just I cannot work out how to do this as I cannot use a file descriptor that is not mapped to something.  I did not want to have to go via a file and without doing this I cannot work out how to make the mapping via a yet unused FD as trying to assign the mapping at either end seem to fail as the FD is not yet assigned.  If I previously assign a FD to a file, it works, but, surly I can stream via a FD without having to go via a file?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, but I guess you want to set a user-defined variable name to the 1st available file descriptor.

If that's the case, your function should simply echo the fd number:

```
getFD() {
  ...
  echo $myFD
}
```

And then let's say `foo` contains the variable name to store the fd into, let's assume it contains the string `bar`:

```
eval $foo=`getFD`
```

After that variable `bar` will contain the first available fd.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, although unfortunately what I am trying to do is significantly more complicated than that.  The function I have already sets the FD variable to be the next file descriptor that is available.  As I state in my question I have already tried adding an echo at the end (just in the form of a printf to keep it clean and portable with no [CR] at the end), however, what I want is a function or command that can be executed in some fashion, possibly with some alias translation, to stream the pipeline leading up to that commands execution into the var name given in its first arg.

Comment: e.g:
`$ someCommand | anotherCommand | myCommand nameOfVarToSet`
where `nameOfVarToSet` is an exported variable containing all text that would have been displayed on the terminal if `myCommand` had not been there.  Another words `nameOfVarToSet` contains what the user would have seen if they ran:
`$ someCommand | anotherCommand` # by itself, the problem being that as each command in a pipeline is a subshell (excluding the bash4: `$ set +m ; shopt -s lastpipe` method)